# how to store constructed variable name

Tags: php, html

I wold like to get the following variable name:

```
class ClassA
{
    public $my_name_is = "";
    function __construct($tag,$cont = null)
    {
        $this->my_name_is = ???;
    }
}
$OBJ = new ClassA();
echo($OBJ->my_name_is);
```

This should output

```
OBJ
```

Is it possible?

I make tag HTML generator and the id of the tag should be the object name so I must not write it twice:

```
$input_pwd = new tag("td>input TYPE=PASSWORD.box_lg#input_pwd"); //old way
$input_pwd = new tag("td>input TYPE=PASSWORD.box_lg"); //upgraded way
```

should generate:

```
<td><input TYPE=PASSWORD ID='input_pwd' CLASS='box_lg'></td>
```

Comment: Why do you want the variable name? What will you expect of `$foo = $OBJ;echo $foo->my_name_is;` ?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible (but this is PHP, so I might be surprised). Perhaps you could explain why you want to do this, and someone might be able to suggest a better way of achieving whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: @xdazz I have updated the question to make it clear

Comment: @2astalavista To tell the truth, your old way is much better than your upgraded way which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. An object doesn't know the names of variables that refer to it.

"Needing" this is usually a design flaw.

Comment: I've been downvoted in the past for answering a question of the form "Is it possible to do `x`?" with an answer consisting (more or less briefly) of "No, it isn't". I think a minority of users erroneously believe that answers like that are somehow invalid.

Comment: @Hammerite "minority"? Lol, you underestimate this site's usual audience a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the magic constant `__CLASS__` for retrieving the name of the current class, but there is no way for a class to get the name of the variable which stores the class. You may want to extend your class and still use `__CLASS__`:

```
class OBJ extends ClassA {
    public function getName() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
$OBJ = new OBJ();
$OBJ->getName();
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to ensure that each reference to the object has a unique ID, you can do that with a static variable.

```
class ClassA {
    public function getUniqueName() {
        static $count = 0;
        ++$count;
        return __CLASS__ . '.' . $count;
    }
}
$OBJ = new ClassA();
echo($OBJ->getUniqueName();
```

Every time that method is called, it will give you a different result. If you call it only once on each variable, you should be fine.